# UIView animation does not animate subviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, layout, uiview

I have a UIScrollView with some UIViews, which again contain all kinds of other views (labels, text fields, etc.). Now, when I rotate the device I would like to alter the size and position of the views within the scroll view. In order to do so I calculate a set of constraints for both portrait and landscape mode up front and switch the constraints on the scroll view according to the current interface orientation. Basically, this works as expected. The thing is that I do not want the views to be simply put, but smoothly animated into their new positions. And this is where I am completely stuck right now. The basic animation works just fine, i.e. the views within the scroll view are perfectly animated but the *subviews within these views* are simply repositioned and not animated. I use the following code to kick off the animation

```
    NSMutableArray *constraints = UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation) ? self.landscapeConstraints : self.portraitConstraints;

[self.scrollView removeConstraints:self.scrollView.constraints];
[self.scrollView addConstraints:constraints];    

[UIView animateWithDuration:duration
                 animations:^{

                     [self.scrollView layoutIfNeeded];
                 }];
```

As far as I know (and as far as my research goes), this is just how it should be done... but obviously I am wrong and I cannot for the life of me figure out what I need to do differently. At the end of the animation everything is positioned perfectly fine, but the subviews simply refuse to animate. Any help is greatly appreciated!

For the sake of completeness it might be worth mentioning that I load the views that I position within the scroll view from a storyboard where I also set the constraints for their subviews. I think this should not be a problem though, since the layout actually works... except for the animations.